# Override zoom over swipetorefresh - Android

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, pinchzoom, swiperefreshlayout

Okay so if I have scrolled just a little bit and the swipetorefresh gets visible, and if I try to zoom with two fingers it just gets further down to refresh. What I  want to achieve is that if the user tries to zoom, the swipe to refresh to be overridden by the zoom option. Here is some code.

This is the webView simple zoom controls.

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Here is from the SwipeToRefresh:

```
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
         new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
              @Override
              public void onRefresh() {
                   myWebView.reload();
                   }
         });
```

And I have `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` and `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` depending where I want to use them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I successfully solved it with next:

Create new class extended from SwipeRefreshLayout

```
public class SwipeToRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

private static final float REFRESH_RATE = 10f;
private float mDownX, mDownY, scaleX, scaleY;

public SwipeToRefresh(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SwipeToRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = ev.getX();
            mDownY = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return doRefresh(ev);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return doRefresh(ev);
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

private boolean doRefresh(MotionEvent ev) {
    scaleX = Math.abs(ev.getX() - mDownX);
    scaleY = Math.abs(ev.getY() - mDownY);
    if (scaleY / scaleX > REFRESH_RATE) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

In activity

```
  SwipeToRefresh mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeToRefresh) findViewById(R.id.my_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Refresh WebView
        }
    });
```

Donn't forget change class name in layout

```
<com.example.package.SwipeToRefresh
        android:id="@+id/my_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </com.example.package.SwipeToRefresh>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Its a big improvement but still the pinch to zoom doesn't override the swipe to refresh.. If the circle is on the screen and you try to zoom it just moves up or down..

Comment: Great idea. Thanks :)